# react native return image function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How would I call to the function listItems on line 6 to run in the return?
I attempted it with Image and Text but neither would work.

```js
export default class GifPicture extends Component {

render() { 
const gifs = [
    "travel", "wandering", "lost", "best", "earliest-list", "favourites", "writer", "sad", "crying", "death", "learning", "technology", "help", "comedy", "funny", "humor", "humour", "satire", "old", "ancient", "storm", "cloudy", "celebrity", "movies", "blond", "fantasy", "sci-fi", "science-fiction", "sf", "classics", "business", "career", "creativity", "fitness", "happiness", "health", "love", "non-fiction", "nonfiction", "productivity", "relationships", "romance", "self-help", "success", "wellness", "baseball", "sports", "book club", "historical", "literary", "summer", "sunny", "clear", "warm", "autumn", "books", "coffee", "creep", "creepy", "dark", "fall", "fireplace", "freaky", "halloween", "leaves", "november", "october", "pumpkin", "rain", "rainy", "reading", "scary", "september", "spooky", "sweater", "tea", "thanksgiving", "intrigue", "mystery", "thriller", "fiction", "seasons", "setting", "weather", "winter", "cold", "warmup"
];
const listItems = gifs.map((gif) => {
    axios
    .get("https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=#####&tag=cats", {params: {q: {gif}}})
    .then( (results) => { 
        var imageUrl = response.data.image_original_url;

        <Image source = {imageUrl} />
        console.warn(results.data.image_original_url); 
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));   
})  
    return ( 
        <View>
            <Image source= {listItems}/>
    </View>
    );
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be a really easy solution if you weren't doing asynchronous `axios` calls.

When you rely on your app to render content based on an API call, it is common practice to trigger that API call once when your component mounts, using the Component lifecycle called `componentDidUpdate` and save the result of the API call in the state.

Initially, your component will render an empty screen.

Once **all** the images are done downloading, then you can update the state of your component by calling `this.setState()` as seen in the example below:

```
export default class GifPicture extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            imageUrls: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchImageUrls()
    }

    fetchImageUrls = () => {
        const gifs = [
            "travel", "wandering", "lost", "best", "earliest-list", "favourites", "writer", "sad", "crying", "death", "learning", "technology", "help", "comedy", "funny", "humor", "humour", "satire", "old", "ancient", "storm", "cloudy", "celebrity", "movies", "blond", "fantasy", "sci-fi", "science-fiction", "sf", "classics", "business", "career", "creativity", "fitness", "happiness", "health", "love", "non-fiction", "nonfiction", "productivity", "relationships", "romance", "self-help", "success", "wellness", "baseball", "sports", "book club", "historical", "literary", "summer", "sunny", "clear", "warm", "autumn", "books", "coffee", "creep", "creepy", "dark", "fall", "fireplace", "freaky", "halloween", "leaves", "november", "october", "pumpkin", "rain", "rainy", "reading", "scary", "september", "spooky", "sweater", "tea", "thanksgiving", "intrigue", "mystery", "thriller", "fiction", "seasons", "setting", "weather", "winter", "cold", "warmup"
        ];
        Promise.all(
            gifs.map(gif => {
                return axios
                    .get(
                        'https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/random?api_key=#####&tag=cats',
                        { params: { q: { gif } } }
                    )
                    .then(response => {
                        var imageUrl = response.data.image_original_url
                        return imageUrl
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            })
        )
            .then(arrayOfImageUrls => {
                this.setState({ imageUrls: arrayOfImageUrls })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error('Any one of the axios calls failed...', err)
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { imageUrls } = this.state
        return (
            <View>
                {imageUrls.map((imageUrl, index) => (
                    <Image key={index} source={imageUrl} />
                ))}
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Updating the state of your component will trigger a re-render, causing the images to be displayed.

More info about `Component`'s lifecycle methods: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Read about fetching data on React here: https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/